# Random classification forests for extremely sparse response variables

Tags: random-forest, cart, sparse

I have a response variable that can be $A,B,C$. It is very sparse, meaning 99% of the sample is $B$ and the rest is approximately evenly divided between $A$ and $C$.

How do I predict this variable in a random classification forest? I am looking for guidelines:

- Can I use the standard classification splitting criterion with such a sparse response variable?
- Given the asymmetric damage an out of sample misclassification would do (i.e. classifying A or C correctly is most important and B correctly is a lower priority), how do I apply some kind of asymmetric loss function here?
- Are there other special things I need to take into consideration when modelling such a sparse response variable?

Related but not duplicated: [Is there a Random Forest implementation that works well with very sparse data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28828/random-forest-implementation-for-sparse-data)